# How is ~ように used/linked in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntax

In このボクのように*完ペキな仙人*仕様にはまだ成れなかったんだよ彼も！
I thought that it meant "Just like me, not even he could attain the *perfect sage* method!"

However the official translation is
"He couldn't become the perfect sage *that I have become*!"

My understanding or the sentence is that 彼も and このボクのように implies that both persons couldn't attain 完ペキな仙人. Am I correct or is the official translation correct? And why?

Here's a picture for more context, the sequence is 1-2-3 from left to right:

[image: More Context]

Answer (score 3):

The official translation is probably better, because apparently this creature is claiming to be a "perfect sage" himself. (But it depends on the story.)

Probably you're misunderstanding what この僕のように modifies. You're treating この僕のように as something like a sentence adverb, but this この僕のように actually only modifies the na-adjective right after it, 完ペキ. この僕のように完璧な仙人 forms a noun phrase that just means "sage who is as perfect as me" or "perfect sage like me".

If there were a comma after この僕のように, then it's possible to interpret it as a sentence adverb.

> - 彼のように私は英語を話せない。
>     I can't speak English like him. = My English is not as good as his.
> - 彼のように、私は英語を話せない。 (sounds a bit unnatural)
>     Just like him, I can't speak English (either).

**EDIT:** 仕様 here is not a synonym for 仕方（しかた, a way of doing） but a different word meaning "spec". As a suffix, ～仕様 means something like "-grade", "-spec", "-ready", etc (eg 冬仕様 = winter-grade). So strictly speaking, this sentence is talking not about actually becoming a sage but about the "readiness" to become a sage: "He could not be as 'perfect-sage-ready' as me ..." or "His body was not prepared for becoming a perfect sage ..." The official translation seems to have simplified this part.

Comment: In the chat, @Flaw suggested that the 仕様 might change the meaning to something like "the method to become a perfect sage". What do you think about that?

Comment: @Seelentau "この僕のように完璧な仙人仕様" sounds to me like "perfect-like-me sage-form", and I don't think 仕様 changes the way この僕のように should be interpreted. BTW what's the story? Does this snake-like creature say that he's a perfect 仙人, or that he's one of those who failed to become a good 仙人?

Comment: Why isn't the noun-phrase この僕のよう**な**完璧な仙人 instead? ~に made me search for a verb to link it to.

Comment: Hm. Although I admit I find two な used in succession a little strange. In a chain of な-adjectives, all except the final one would link up using で instead.

Comment: @Flaw An adverb can modify an adjective. 本当に怖い話 = a really scaring story; 本当の怖い話 = a real, scaring story